# Viewing objects by themselves vs. through their ActiveRelations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have three models: `Car`, `Manufacturer`, and `ManufacturerCar`.

`Car` and `Manufacturer` are connected through `ManufacturerCar` with a has_many relationship. Users can visit individual car pages to view info about those cars, and same with manufacturers.

Here's the twist: on each manufacturer's page, I also have a list showing all the cars produced by that manufacturer. These items are coming from the `ManufacturerCar` ActiveRelation. What I'm trying to do is allow the user to browse through cars with 'next' and 'previous' on the car page, but *only if* the user arrived at that page from the manufacturer page.

For example, if the user goes directly to the Honda Civic page, don't show the next/prev buttons (since they wouldn't make sense in that context). But if they go to Honda manufacturer page first, and then click on Honda Civic, then I also need to allow them to go to Honda Accord, Honda CR-V, etc. from the Honda Civic page (i.e. without having to go back to the Honda manufacturer page first).

How is this done in Rails?

Comment: This looks like a typical case of "nested resources": See  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, 2.7 Nested Resources. In your routes file, you can define a set of routes for a "nested" Car, and at the same time for a non-nested Car!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to `Danny`, [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) was my original thought, too:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cars
resources :manufacturers do
   resources :cars #-> /manufacturers/3/cars
end
```

--

This will allow you to create two sets of views (or `actions`, depending on how you want to structure your controllers):

```
#app/views/cars/index.html.erb
# ... stuff here
<% if @manufacturer.present? %>
   <%= render partial: "manufacturers/cars", locals: { manufacturer: @manufacturer } %>
<% end %>


#app/views/manufacturers/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: "cars", locals: { manufacturer: @manufacturer } %>


#app/views/manufacturers/_cars.html.erb
<% for car in manufacturer.cars do %>
      <%= car.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Sorry for the late response - the feature got cut from the first release and I just got around to implementing it. :)